# Is there a more idiomatic way of creating an index buffer in Rust

Tags: vector, rust, struct, index-buffer

In computer graphics, one of the most basic patterns is creating several buffers for vertex attributes and an index buffer that groups these attributes together.

In Rust, this basic pattern looks like this:

```rust
struct Position { ... }
struct Uv { ... }

struct Vertex {
    pos: usize,
    uv: usize
}

// v_vertex[_].pos is an index into v_pos
// v_vertex[_].uv is an index into v_uv
struct Object {
    v_pos: Vec<Position>, // attribute buffer
    v_uv: Vec<Uv>, // attribute buffer
    v_vertex: Vec<Vertex> // index buffer
}
```

However, this pattern leaves a lot to be desired. Any operations to the attribute buffers that modifies existing data is going to be primarily concerned with making sure the index buffer isn't invalidated. In short, it leaves most of the promises the rust compiler is capable of making on the table.

Making a scheme like this work isn't impossible. For example, the struct could include a `HashMap` that keeps track of changed indices and rebuilds the vectors when it gets too large. However, all the workarounds inevitably feel like another hack that doesn't address the underlying problem: there is no compile-checked guarantee that I'm not introducing data races or that the "reference" hasn't been invalidated somewhere else on accident.

When I first approached this problem when moving from C++ to Rust, I tried to make the `Vertex` object hold references to the attributes. That looked something like this:

```rust
struct Position { ... }
struct Uv { ... }

struct Vertex {
    pos: &Position,
    uv: &Uv
}

// obj.v_vertex[_].pos is a reference to an element of obj.v_pos
// obj.v_vertex[_].uv is a reference to an element of obj.v_uv
// This causes a lot of problems; it's effectively impossible to use
struct Object {
    v_pos: Vec<Position>,
    v_uv: Vec<Uv>,
    v_vertex: Vec<Vertex>
}
```

...Which threw me down deep into the rabbit holes of self-referential structs and why they cannot exist in safe Rust. After learning more about, it turns out that as I suspected, the original implementation hid a lot of unsafety pitfalls that were caught by the compiler when I started being more explicit.

I'm aware of the existence unsafe solutions like `Pin`, but I feel like at that point I might as well stick to the original method.

This leads me to the core question: Is there an idiomatic way of representing this relationship? I want to be able to modify the contents of each of the `Vec`s in a compiler-checked manner.

Comment: Can you explain exactly which operations you're trying to support here?

Comment: @NicolBolas Ideally whatever you could do with any other collection (it's just a `Vec` for ease of demonstration), but primarily I need to be able to add, remove, and modify elements of each of the `Vec`s in a safe manner.

Comment: Here's what I mean. You can insert a new `Vertex` into the collection. The position within that `Vertex` may or may not already be inside the collection. If it is, you need to be able to find it, which *itself* raises questions about doing a bunch of 3-element floating-point equality checks. And if it isn't there, you need to add it to the end. So: do you *really* want this operation to be *atomic*, something you can do from multiple threads on the same object?

Comment: Something similar goes for element removal. The same position could be indexed multiple times, so you can't remove it unless you search the index list for a matching index. Is that a thing that you really want to be atomic? Modification is similar.  Making any of this stuff thread-safe doesn't sound like a good idea from a performance perspective.

Comment: @NicolBolas I think I understand what you're saying in both cases but that isn't what I'm asking. I want to be able to replace the raw indices with references in a way that doesn't lock up the borrow checker (as the second snippet does) or use unsafe Rust. Perhaps I do have some fundamental misconceptions about what that entails, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an idiomatic way of representing this relationship?

The `usize`s you started with *are* the idiomatic way of representing this relationship.

> Any operations to the attribute buffers that modifies existing data is going to be primarily concerned with making sure the index buffer isn't invalidated. …

Yes; you should write those operations within the module that defines `Object`, and keep the fields private so the `Object` cannot become inconsistent as long as those operations are correctly defined.

> In short, it leaves most of the promises the rust compiler is capable of making on the table.

It doesn't — because the Rust compiler is not actually capable of making those promises. `&` and even `&mut` references are actually very limited — they work by statically enforcing “Nobody (else) is going to change this value while you have the reference”. They don't have *any* bigger picture than that. In your case, assuming you're planning to edit this data, you will need to do operations *that modify multiple parts in a consistent fashion*, like “add a Position and also a Vertex that uses it”, or maybe “simultaneously add 3 vertices making up a triangle, using these 3 existing Positions”. References cannot help you do this correctly.

The only kind of data structure of this sort that you can in fact build using references is an *append-only* one, using the help of, for example, [`typed-arena`](https://docs.rs/typed-arena/). This might be suitable for an algorithm which is building a mesh. However, given that it's append-only, there is very little benefit — the operation “append a vertex, choosing indices as you go” is easy to write correctly *without* references. Additionally, you won't be able to store the mesh constructed that way long-term (because it is made of vectors that borrow from the arena) unless you also throw in [`ouroboros`](https://docs.rs/ouroboros/) to wrap up the self-reference.

Fundamentally, references are designed to be used as **temporary** things — as a formalization and enforcement of common patterns used in C and C++ when passing and returning pointers — hence also being called “borrows”. The rules which the compiler understands about references are rules designed to handle those temporary uses. They are almost never what you should be building a data structure out of.